# How make the react component read or edit based on HOC function in navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, uinavigationcontroller

I want to make components read or edit based on the authorization. Example

```
const auth = "read" || "edit"
```

if auth is read users can only allow read the component. If auth is edit the user can allow to edit the component.

How to wrap all the component to global HOC function and based on the auth how to navigate.

**navigationContainer**

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginComponent">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="LoginScreen"
        component={LoginComponent}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
 <Stack.Screen
        name="Upload"
        component={Uploadcompoenent}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

**condition**

1.let consider if the user supervisor then the user can do upload the new image. 2.if the user is an assistant supervisor the user can only read the screen. for the assistant supervisor upload option is disabled.

I want to put all the components into one HOC function based on the auth user can read or upload the image.

Thanks,

Any leads will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering a component <Stack.Navigator/> as HOC which will render a couple of child elements.

Inside Stack.Navigator component you will have your auth value which can be passed to all the child components using React.Children.map in this way:

```
export default function ParentComp(props) {
  const auth = 'edit';

  return React.Children.map(props.children, (child, i) => {
    let el = React.cloneElement(child, {
      auth
    });
    return el;
  });
}
```

So, your Child components will accept your auth state as props which would be used to block certain events on your child component.

```
export default function ChildComp(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      component is only {props.auth} {props.test}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: How to wrap this parentComp into navigation container

Comment: Parent component can be your <Stack.Navigator/>